# Regex - Validate Closing tag - Template Engine

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string

For a particular template engine, where user will add/update templates to send messages to customers.

I am using regular expressions to validate each template literals having double tags, a starting `<<` and closing `>>` tag  in a string.

Given is valid template engine.

```
Hi <<cName>>, please make your payment of $ <<totAmt>>   
for Account number <<accNum>> given by <<agentName>> at this link <<payLink>>
The validity of this link is 30 minutes.
```

Given are **`valid`**  template literals
`<<cName>>`
`<<totAmt>>`
`<<accNum>>`
`<<agentName>>`
`<<payLink>>`

Given are **`invalid`**  template literals
`<<cName>`
`<<agentName>>>>>>>>`
`<cName>`
`<<<<<payLink>>`
`<<cName<<>>`

Currently give is my workaround.

First I get all template literals using given Regex.

> <.*?>(?!>)

Then loop through each literals to validate using given Regex in PHP. If any literal is invalid, so given template updated by user is invalid.

> ^<{2}[^<>]+>{2}(?!>)

```
$is_tpl_valid = true; //template is valid

$template = 'Hi <<cName>>, please make your payment of $ <<totAmt>>   
for Account number <<accNum>> given by <agentName>> at this link <<payLink>>
The validity of this link is 30 minutes.';

echo '<br/> --- File: ' . __FILE__ . '#'. __LINE__ . '------- $template -> ' . $template . ' --------------<br/>';
if(preg_match_all('#<.*?>(?!>)#', $template, $matched))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matched);
    foreach($matched[0] as $item)
    {
        if($is_tpl_valid && !preg_match('#^<{2}[^<>]+>{2}(?!>)#', $item))
        {
            echo '<br/> --- File: ' . __FILE__ . '#'. __LINE__ . '------- $item -> ' .  $item . ' --------------<br/>';
            $is_tpl_valid = false; //template is invalid
        }
    }
}
```

Can we do it in single Regex or any better solution (in JS / PHP) to find invalid template literals.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're validating with JS or PHP ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract all literals that are invalid? Share some sample string with expected result(s).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have added valid and invalid literals patterns.

Comment: @CodeManiac, currently php but a solution in JS will be good for future Frontend validation.

Comment: @Anon30 [`^(<<(?>[^<>\n]+|(?1))>>)$`](https://regex101.com/r/nHn6uX/1/) is this what you're after ?

Comment: `<<<cname>>>` should it match ?

Comment: @CodeManiac No, it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.

This will attempt to match valid tags then FAIL or match everything with the form `<+blah>+` that are, in fact, invalid:

```
$text = '
<<cName>>
<<totAmt>>
<<accNum>>
<<agentName>>
<<payLink>>

<<cName>
<<agentName>>>>>>>>
<cName>
<<<<<payLink>>
<<cName<<>> 
';

preg_match_all('/(?<!<)<<\w+>>(?!>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<+[\w<]+>+/', $text, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <<cName>
            [1] => <<agentName>>>>>>>>
            [2] => <cName>
            [3] => <<<<<payLink>>
            [4] => <<cName<<>>
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

To validate tags you can try this pattern

```
(?<!<)<<[^<>]+>>(?!>)
```

- `(?<!<)` - Match should not be preceded by `<`
- `<<` - Match `<<`
- `[^<>]+` - Match anything except `<>`
- `>>` - Match `>>`
- `(?!>)` - Match should not be followed by `>`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/K44OnG/1/)

Comment: it is same as my solution. I need to find if any literals is invalid in any given template.

Comment: @Anon30 you're already capturing all the tags right ? you can filter the tags which are not correct using this regex

Comment: Yes, my existing code do the same. But I need better and faster solution.